# Vivado: post-synthesis simulation fails to start, although behavioral runs

Tags: vhdl, simulation, synthesis, vivado

I have a module in Xilinx Vivado that fails to run post-synthesis simulation with followinf errors:

```
Starting static elaboration

ERROR: [VRFC 10-380] binding entity insertion_sort does not have generic array_length 
ERROR: [VRFC 10-718] formal port <sort_in> does not exist in entity <insertion_sort>.  Please compare the definition of block <insertion_sort> to its component declaration and its instantion to detect the mismatch. 
ERROR: [VRFC 10-718] formal port <sorted_out> does not exist in entity <insertion_sort>.  Please compare the definition of block <insertion_sort> to its component declaration and its instantion to detect the mismatch. 
ERROR: [XSIM 43-3321] Static elaboration of top level VHDL design unit sort_tb in library work failed.
```

But behavioral simulation and the synthesis itself run normally.

```
INFO: [Common 17-83] Releasing license: Synthesis
21 Infos, 0 Warnings, 0 Critical Warnings and 0 Errors encountered.
synth_design completed successfully
```

here is the description of the module

```
entity insertion_sort is
    generic(
        array_length:integer:=9
    );
    Port (
        clk: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        start_sorting: in std_logic;
        sort_in: in array_of_ints (0 to array_length-1);
        sorted_out: out array_of_ints(0 to array_length-1);
        sort_ready: out std_logic
    );

end insertion_sort;
```

array_of_ints is defined in the package as

```
package array_def is
    type array_of_ints is array (natural range<>) of integer range -200 to 200 ;

end package;
```

instantiation of the module in the test bench

```
entity sort_tb is
    generic(
     tb_length: integer:=9
    );
    --Port ( );
end;

architecture test_sorting of sort_tb is

    constant clock_cycle: time:=20 ns;
    signal start, ready, tclk, rst: std_logic;
    signal test_array_in, test_array_out: array_of_ints(0 to tb_length-1);
    signal  run_num: positive:=1;
    component insertion_sort
        generic ( array_length: integer);
        port(
            clk: in std_logic;
            reset: in std_logic;
            start_sorting: in std_logic;
            sort_in: in array_of_ints (0 to array_length-1);
            sorted_out: out array_of_ints(0 to array_length-1);
        sort_ready: out std_logic);

    end component;

    begin
    DUT: insertion_sort 
    generic map( array_length=>tb_length)
    port map (clk=>tclk,
        reset=>rst,
        start_sorting=>start,
        sort_in=>test_array_in,
        sorted_out=>test_array_out,
    sort_ready=>ready  );
```

Hope i provided enough information. Thank you in advance for your help

**EDIT:** entity description from new file created by vivado as requested by Paebbels.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VCOMPONENTS.ALL;
entity insertion_sort is
  port (
    clk : in STD_LOGIC;
    reset : in STD_LOGIC;
    start_sorting : in STD_LOGIC;
    \sort_in[0]\ : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sort_in[1]\ : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sort_in[2]\ : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sort_in[3]\ : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sort_in[4]\ : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sort_in[5]\ : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sort_in[6]\ : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sort_in[7]\ : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sort_in[8]\ : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sorted_out[0]\ : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sorted_out[1]\ : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sorted_out[2]\ : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sorted_out[3]\ : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sorted_out[4]\ : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sorted_out[5]\ : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sorted_out[6]\ : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sorted_out[7]\ : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    \sorted_out[8]\ : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 8 downto 0 );
    sort_ready : out STD_LOGIC
  );
  attribute NotValidForBitStream : boolean;
  attribute NotValidForBitStream of insertion_sort : entity is true;
  attribute array_length : integer;
  attribute array_length of insertion_sort : entity is 9;
end insertion_sort;
```

Comment: Post- synthesis models have no generics. There is a new VHDL file created from your netlist, comprising all RTL technology elements. You need a new testbench, without generic values. Please search for this file and post its entity definition, so we can check it.

Comment: I added the requested file to the post

Comment: As you can see, Vivado flattended your 9x9 vector to 9 vectors of 9 bits. The used generic was transformed into an attribute and set to 9. So you need to write a new testbench, which matches this entity description.

Comment: I have learned something today :D. Do I take the signals as they are, with  backslashes '\'?

Comment: Create a wrapper, a new architecture for your "insertion_sort" entity, which instantiates the post-synthesis entity, and performs type conversions on all the ports that require them. (You can use intermediate signals to help).

Comment: I don't know what's up with the backslashes. They are not part of an valid port name. Are they used in the architecture or is it just an export bug? => Try and error ... Please report your solution, I'm interested!

Comment: As far as I understood this a simply so called extended identifiers http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/names.html.
But still not sure how this would affect instantiation